# json save object to list

Tags: c#, json

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     List<Movie> _data = new List<Movie>();
     _data.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(File.ReadAllText(@"mov.txt")));

        Console.ReadKey();
}}

[{"Name" : "John","Year" : "1990"},
  {"Name" : "Mark","Year" : "2005"}]
```

Theres Exception:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'testjson.Movie' because the type requires a
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Error itself tell you it's required a proper json in form of Movie class to Deserialize it

Comment: why don't you first try to serialize it and then compare the result with the content of the file?

Comment: The JSON presented appears to be an array, something that would appear within a JSON package. Needs something like {"movies":[...]}

Comment: @Matt no, JSON doesn't _have_ to be an object. Just a string or array is valid JSON too.

Comment: @CodeCaster, while true, I have found that Deserializing methods (generally) need a named connection between the JSON package and the C# object, otherwise it doesn't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a JSON array, so you need to deserialize as such:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie[]>
```

So you can call `AddRange()`, which accepts an `IEnumerable<Movie>`:

```
_data.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie[]>(File.ReadAllText(@"mov.txt")));
```

But in this case you can deserialize the list itself:

```
List<Movie> _data;
_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(File.ReadAllText(@"mov.txt")));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (thanks to CodeCaster):

```
_data.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(File.ReadAllText(@"mov.txt")));
```

because *this*

```
[ 
  { ... },
  { ... },
  ...
]
```

in your json means that *it is* an array. So you have to deserialize it as an array.

Comment: _"try"_ - explain why.

Comment: it's a list of Movie so it's required a Movie Item and you have added List of Movie

Comment: I think what @Dhaval is trying to say is that you can't call `List<T>.Add(List<T>)`. You need `AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's true. wanted to be fast... and missed the `List<T>.Add`. thx mate.